# Ruby if oneliner inside if statement yields error

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Here's an unexpected find. Something of a very basic Ruby issue that I haven't happened to run into before:

```
a = "a"

if a
  test = "yes" if a == "a" else "no"
else
  test = "no"
end
```

Running this yields the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected kELSE, expecting kEND
```

Looks like the nested oneliner spills out into the enclosing if statement. What's the generalized solution for this? Not using a oneliner inside an exploded if statement? (It works when exploding the enclosed conditional because it is terminated by an `end` keyword.

BTW, This is a minimized contrived example, so no need to explain its stupidity or question why I'd do this. I'm looking for a general explanation of how to prevent ruby oneliner if statements from spilling into enclosing conditional scopes.

Comment: "yes" if a == "a" else "no" looks like the Python conditional expression, but definitely not Ruby.

Comment: Uh, oops. I've been a Pythonista for 15+ years. I think when I type fast, it comes out Python, even when I'm typing Ruby :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to put `if else` into one line, use `then` like this:

```
if a then b else c end
```

and, if you want, you can use `;` instead of `then`, like this:

```
if a ; b else c end
```

Also, sometimes you can use this instead of `?:`:

```
a && b || c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
test = "yes" if a == "a" else "no"
```

does not work because the language does not allow it, try

```
test = a == "a" ? "yes" : "no"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you are using an 'if modifier' in this line:

```
test = "yes" if a == "a" else "no"
```

if modifiers only accept one condition - therefore the `syntax error, unexpected kELSE, expecting kEND`

As mentioned by others, ternary operators are ideal for these one-liners.

Comment: I suspect the syntax error arises from the outer `if` seeing two `else` in a row.

Comment: Possibly, but you get the same error if you terminate the inner if with an end...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than duplicate the "no" answer in both your outer `if` and `else` blocks, I'd rewrite the whole thing:

```
a = "a"
test = if a && a == "a"
         "yes"
       else
         "no"
       end
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
a = "a"
test = (a && a == "a") ? "yes" : "no"
```